# Keeping fileowner and permissions after copying file in C

Tags: c, permissions, file-ownership

here is my problem: In C, I create the copy of a file (with some changes) This is done trivially via fopen(), getchar and putchar.
Copying the file is fine and the outputfile itself is what I want it to be.

My problem is: I assume that I will use this program often as sudo and then the resulting file has both another owner (root) as well as different permissions (execute rights are gone).

My question is: How can I copy the owner and permissions of the original file and then write them into the new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *fstat*(2) system call to obtain the details about the owner and the permissions, and the *fchmod*(2) and *fchown*(2) system calls to set them.  See an example in the *setfile* function of the *BSD *cp*(1) [source code](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/~checkout~/src/bin/cp/utils.c?rev=1.61;content-type=text/plain).

Comment: ... or `fstat(fileno(source))` and `fchown(fileno(dest))`, to prevent race conditions.

Answer (score 2):

since you use fopen():

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//fp is your source filepointer, fdest is your dest filepointer
//fn is the  new filename you're copying to

struct stat fst;
//let's say this wont fail since you already worked OK on that fp
fstat(fileno(fp),&fst);
//update to the same uid/gid
fchown(fileno(fdest),fst.st_uid,fst.st_gid);
//update the permissions 
fchmod(fileno(fdest),fst.st_mode);
```

as a quick note, you may want to fread() and fwrite() instead of f*char()'ing

Answer (score 0):

Under linux use the libc fchmod and fchown
Manpages can be found here:

http://linux.die.net/man/2/fchmod

http://linux.die.net/man/2/fchown