# Linux C, creating new file with the same permissions as an existing file

Tags: c, file, permissions

I have to create a program that will create new one or overwrite existing(*outfile*) file, with the content of an already existing file(*infile*). For me, this is easy, I've already done this. But my problem is, that *outfile* needs to have same permission as *infile* and I have no idea how to do this.

*programName infile outfile*

My code looks like this, I think that I need to use stat() or fstat() but I'm not really sure how.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char* infile = argv[1];
    char* outfile = argv[2];

    int in = open(infile, O_RDONLY, S_IRUSR);
    int out = open(outfile, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    long len = lseek(in, 0L, SEEK_END);
    char buf[len];
    lseek(in, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    read(in, &buf, len);
    write(out, &buf, len);
    close(in);
    close(out);
    return 0;
}
```

I know that right now I've set permission manually.

Comment: Use `stat()`  to read the permissions from the source file and `chown()/chmod()` to set them on the target file.

Comment: Given you already have open file descriptors, you can use `fstat()`, `fchown()`, and `fchmod()`.  That also has the advantage of avoiding possible race conditions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keeping fileowner and permissions after copying file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486774/keeping-fileowner-and-permissions-after-copying-file-in-c)